# Hadoop for MySQL use cases

Tags: mysql, hadoop, bigdata, groupwise-maximum

I have a database with ~4 million records of US stocks, mutual funds and ETFs prices for 5 years and every day I am adding daily price for each security.

For one feature that I am working on I need to fetch latest price for each security (groupwise max) and do some calculation with other financial metrics. 
The securities count is ~40K.

But the groupwise maximum with this amount of data is heavy and takes minutes to execute.

Of course my tables use indexes, but the task involves getting and real time processing nearly 7GB data.

So I am interested, is this task for Big Data tools and algorithms or it is small amount of data? because in examples I noticed that they are working on data of thousands and millions GBs.

My database is MySQL and I want to use Hadoop to process data.
Is it good practice or I need to use only MySQL optimizations (is my data small?) or if it is wrong to use Hadoop in that amount of data, what can you advice for this case?

**NOTE** that my increasing every day and project involves many analyzes, that need to be done on real time, based on user request.

**NOTE** Don't know whether this question is OK to ask in stackoverflow, so please sorry if question is off-topic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hadoop terms, your data is definitely small. Latest computers have 16+ GB of RAM, therefore your dataset can entirely fit into memory of a single machine.

However, that doesn't mean you can at least attempt to load data into HDFS and perform some operation over it. Sqoop & Hive would be the tools you would use to load and have SQL processing.

Since I brought up the point about memory, though, it is entirely feasible you don't need Hadoop (HDFS & YARN), and can instead use [Apache Spark w/ SparkSQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) to hit MySQL directly from a distributed JDBC connection.

Comment: Thank you for response! can you show some info about difference of Hadoop and Spark, sorry if question is silly, I am newbie on Big Data :)

Comment: Hadoop is an ecosystem of tools, at which the core is a distributed filesystem (HDFS), the system resource manager for managing the cluster CPU and memory (YARN), and the framework for running code (MapReduce). Spark only concerns itself with being a better version of MapReduce, and it can optionally use YARN to schedule it's processes within a cluster, and optionally reads data from HDFS. There isn't a **difference**, they play well together.

Comment: Thank you, so roughly Spark is more big data computational thing and Hadoop is for storing big data.

Comment: Yup. But Spark runs fine on a single machine too. "Big data" doesn't just mean size, by the way.  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140306073407-64875646-big-data-the-5-vs-everyone-must-know/

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can take advantage of indexes, and achieve the goal with Order(M), where M is the number of securities (40K) instead of O(N) where N is the number of rows in the table.

Here is an [*example*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#using_an_uncorrelated_subquery) that needs adapting.